# JavaScript: First character of the array is missing when using array.join() function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this code:

```
var elements_var = "Csus2 FM Dm CM";
var elements = ["Csus2","FM","Dm","CM"];

var note_var = (elements.join('\xa0'));

console.log("elements.join output:")
console.log(note_var);

console.log("Regular string output:")
console.log(elements_var);
note_2 = note_var;


const chordsClip = scribble.clip({
    // Use chord names directly in the notes array
    // M stands for Major, m stands for minor

    notes: note_var,
    pattern: 'x---'.repeat(4)
});
```

And this is the Console output:

[image: Console Output]

As you can see while console displays **"Csus2 FM Dm Cm"** correctly in both regular string **(elements_var)** and elements.join output **(note_var)**, note_var seems to be missing it's first char when passing it to another function.

Function works perfectly when **elements_var** is inserted instead of note_var. What's happening? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `\xa0` is a non-breaking space, so your strings are not equivalent.  Why not use a space instead?

Comment: The comment in your code seems to suggest that the `notes` property must be set to an array, not a string.

Comment: I think this is the `scribbletune` library.  Can you confirm, OP?

Comment: I don't know I always used \xa0 so I'm used to it. Now I've used \u0020 and it worked. But still it's a question in my mind why does this happen when using \xa0 ?

Comment: @trincot If I've identified the right library, [it can be either a string or an array of strings](https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune/blob/7e7ccf83741659217cf63e28b422ac4262c02778/src/typings.d.ts#L26)

Comment: @Cactuser Why not just use `' '`?  A simple space.

Comment: I've tried  ' ' it also doesn't work.

Comment: @Cactuser What do you mean it didn't work?  `"\u0020"` and `" "` are the same exact thing.    `'\u0020' === ' '` ==> true

Comment: Yes you're right. I don't know it's a part of the bigger code so I may get lost in the context. Tried now it works. But I remember like I've tried it before and didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using **\u0020** instead of **\xa0** solved the problem.

But still don't know why this happen when using \u0020 cause it has nothing to do with the first char of the first element in the array.

Comment: \u0020 is the space symbol.

Comment: No1 said it's not. Why it doesn't replace the first char of the first element in array but \xa0 does? the question was that.

Comment: Because the library expects spaces, not non-breaking spaces.  Report it to them if you consider it a bug.

Comment: If you're wondering why you see `sus2` instead of `Csus2` is because the error thrown on [line 47](https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune/blob/7e7ccf83741659217cf63e28b422ac4262c02778/src/chord.ts#L47) is using the `chordName` which was set from [line 24](https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune/blob/7e7ccf83741659217cf63e28b422ac4262c02778/src/chord.ts#L24) which _does not include_ the first character of the tokenized name. I'd spend more time tracing it through but without a running working example, that's all I could come up with.

Comment: @chazsolo I know why the error is thrown mate thanks. Does any1 besides Amy reads the things above? I'm curious about why \xa0 is removing first char.

Comment: @Amy I think, it's a bug. Cause I've been using \xa0 for so long and not encountered  something like that happen before.